# Django URL Reset Password Error

Tags: python, django, formularios

Tengo el siguiente problema con las URL del sistema de autenticación de `Django`.

Solicito reiniciar mi contraseña, me llega un mail con el siguiente enlace:

http://itdev:9000/account/reset/MQ/4yk-acbef68e6649f34fdd75/

Luego de eso, entro a ese enlace y me lleva a la siguiente URL:

http://itdev:9000/account/reset/MQ/set-password/

El problema está ahí, donde me da el siguiente error:

`NoReverseMatch at /account/reset/MQ/set-password/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/reset/(?P<uidb64>.+)/(?P<token>.+)/$']`

En el archivo urls.py tengo:

`url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>.+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm')`

también probé de esta manera:

`url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm')`

Pero no hay caso! Se rompe y me tira error 500.

Es Django 2.1. A alguien le pasó?
En qué le estoy errando?

En Django 1.11 me funciona lo más bien.
Aguardo sus respuestas. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3-AbVnls_8&list=PLpOqH6AE0tNgL7Jg9Kx4SdfA5_oK6292j&index=25 aqui esta un ejemplo de como hacerlo

Comment: No funciona esa solución. Puse la URL tal cual esta ahí y tampoco. No hay casi, se sigue rompiendo. Que complicadooooo.

Comment: ¿Estás usando 2.1 o 1.11? En las versiones 2 de Django ya no se usa `url()`, ahora se usa `path()`.

Comment: Cesar! Si, estoy usando 2.1.
Con path las URL tampoco funcionann! :/ tenes un ejemplo hecho?